# SQL Server setup error

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2014

I am trying to open again SQL setup from SQL Server Installation center so when i click on installation and click on
**"New SQL stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation"**

i am trying to add new features that's why i click on that after that they asked select folder so i select from d drive where SQL setup is placed when i select this shows an error

`D:\D Drive\softwares\Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition with SP1 X64` is not a valid installation folder

how to resolve this?

check image please where i select folder

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDw18.png

and this is sql setup files 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytpIn.png

Comment: Is it asking where the setup files are, or where the sqlserver is installed? And which of these are you choosing when you pick d drive..?

Comment: Select the folder containing `setup.exe` rather than the D drive root. You can also run setup.exe directly rather than from the SQL Server Installation Center.

Comment: could you add an image of that window where ask for select a folder? try to look at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/mssqlfun/2014/06/26/sql-server-2014-how-to-add-features-to-existing-instance-/

Comment: @M84 check last links please